# Some binary-data bytes are missing when sending between nodes using express

Tags: node.js, express, http, binary

I'm setting up a server which sends binary data upon request.
On the sending end i'm using express:

```
res.write(chunk);
```

On the receiving side i'm using HTTP request:

```
res.on('data', (chunk) => { 
   file.write(chunk); 
});
```

Some bytes are missing (and I noticed it's always numbers 0x30-0x39) on the receiving end.

What am I doing wrong?

(Node version - v10.16.0)

I tried to set encoding to null, content-type to 'image/png', none worked.

I expect to get the same binary the other node sends, but receiving almost same with some bytes missing.

Comment: Did you call `res.end()` after writing all the content?

Comment: @Praveenkumar Yes I did.